# Вёрстка картинки

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть картинка которая внутри пустая и в эту полость нужно вставить картинку, но только через html. Уже целый день пытаюсь что-то сделать но не получается.

БЫЛО

[image: a busy cat]

СТАЛО

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.layout {
  position: relative;
}
 
#layout-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 344px;
  height: 194px;
  left: 53px;
  top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
            <img id="layout-1" src="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2018/08/0a0baf142bbeccfd4fbf15b0d7e503f6.png" alt="" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute;">
            <img id="layout-2" src="https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/04/005b48e5767933f8710b9780428f794d.jpg" alt="" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute;">
</div>
```